# Check for specific consecutive value in list

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list with values as:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,15,18,20,21,22,28]
```

Now how to check in a loop for consecutive value at threshold 4, such that if 4 consecutive value occurs it skips all those and go ahead with 5th one.
Its output will be like:

```
ans = [1,5,15,18,20,28]
```

Comment: I don't understand, how `1,2,3,4,5,6` translates to `5`, and why `21,22` disappear.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to find groups of consecutive values. There might be more elegant ways, but you can e.g. use a simple `for` loop and compare to the last element in the previous group (if any):

```
grps = []
for i, x in enumerate(l):
    if i == 0 or x > grps[-1][-1] + 1:
        grps.append([x])
    else:
        grps[-1].append(x)
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [15], [18], [20, 21, 22], [28]]
```

Then, just take the fourth element from each group:

```
res = [x for g in grps for x in g[::4]]
# [1, 5, 15, 18, 20, 28]
```